# boolean values set to true unintentionally changing to false

Tags: go

In my golang application, I'm setting some global variables to true based on form input, and then discovering that they have changed to false when used in a subsequent function. Question, what is the proper way to declare and set Boolean values in golang?

```
var withKetchup bool
var withMustard bool

func orderProcess(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

     r.ParseForm()
     withKetchup := r.FormValue("withKetchup")  //set to true (in form js form selection)
     withMustard := r.FormValue("withMustard")  //set to true

      code omitted ///
}

func prepareOrder(){

      code omitted//
     fmt.Println(withKetchup, withMustard) //both are false even though initially set to true
     if withKetchup == true && withMustard == true{

     }else {

     }


}
```

Comment: Global variables storing per-request data? What if you get two overlapping requests?

Comment: `if withKetchup == true` is the same as `if withKetchup`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code

```
 withKetchup := r.FormValue("withKetchup")
```

declares and sets a local variable of type string using a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations). To set the global bool variable, convert the statement to an assignment by removing the ":". Also, compute a bool value by comparing the form value with "":

```
 withKetchup = r.FormValue("withKetchup") == "true"
```

Because the server executes handlers concurrently, it's not safe to use a global variable like this. I suggest passing the values as arguments to prepareOrder:

```
func orderProcess(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

     r.ParseForm()
     withKetchup := r.FormValue("withKetchup") == "true"
     withMustard := r.FormValue("withMustard") == "true"
     prepareOrder(withKetchup, withMustard)
}

func prepareOrder(withKetchup, withMustard bool){
     if withKetchup == true && withMustard == true{

     }else {

     }
}
```

Comment: ok, thank you for the suggestion. After removing the `:` as you indicated, I got another error, that I can't use r.FormValue("withKetchup") (type string) as type bool in assignment. Note, I had set the form values using Booleans in javascript. Any idea what be the problem (which I need to solve before trying your solution) (This is before trying your suggestion of passing them as parameters)

Comment: thanks, however, the `!= ""` code is now setting the values to `true` no matter what, even if the Boolean false is passed through the form.Double checked twice.

Comment: I printed r.FormValue to the Chrome consule, it says "true" when I check true, and "false" when I check/send false

Comment: I found a way around the problem by sending a string and reading the content of the string, and then setting a bool in the go code based on the content of the string, however, that's just a way to avoid the problem of why the js bool is not translating as I intended to go

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking me to do `r.FormValue("withMustard") == "true".`

Comment: ok, see your edit, but what if the order is without ketchup? That doesn't give me a possibility to set it to false, does it? ` r.FormValue("withKetchup") == "true"`